# Change ListView Text Color in Simple ListView - Android

Tags: android

I am using Simple Listview to display Email addresses from Contact List. Its working fine. Now I want to change the color of text displaying email address on each row as I am displaying background for Listview.

Please give me your suggestions or any code. How can I change color?

This is the code:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listSendEmailFinal"
     android:layout_below="@+id/btnAddRecepients"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dip" 
     android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
    android:background="@drawable/listview_border"
     android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
     >
</ListView>
```

Where listview_border.xml is:

```
<stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#83F52C" />
<padding android:left="2dp"
    android:top="2dp"
    android:right="2dp"
    android:bottom="2dp" />
<corners android:radius="10dp" />
<solid android:color="#E6E6FA" />
```

And this the listview coding:

```
mainListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(AddReceiverDialog.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, lv_arr));

mainListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
```

Comment: show us your code what you are trying?

Comment: Hi Akki, I've edited my question with code

Comment: how about the xml for the row?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems you are using Simple adapter not custom adapter.

In this case you can create a theme with text desired text color and apply that theme in manifest file to your ListActivity.

create a xml file in values folder and paste this code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="mytheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
       <item name="android:textColor">#2A88AA</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

and use attach this theme with activity like

```
 <activity
     android:theme="@style/mytheme"
    .
    .
```

Comment: Yes I am using ArrayAdapter. Where should I write this code??